# How to catch 'sys.webforms.pagerequestmanagertimeoutexception' in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I am getting this issue 'sys.webforms.pagerequestmanagertimeoutexception' sometimes while fetching data from RSS Feed. This issue only comes when the response don't come within 90 seconds. How to catch/overcome this issue?

Comment: Why doesn't a regular try/catch pattern work?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution to my issue myself on the web. Here is the code through which `sys.webforms.pagerequestmanagertimeoutexception` can be handled.

Following code needs to be added in within  tags.

```
  Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        if (args.get_error() != undefined) {
            args.set_errorHandled(true);
            //location.reload(true);
            alert("Timeout Exception. Please try again or refresh the page")
        }
    }
```